# Access to a NFT in other's wallet

Tags: tokens, nft, smart-contract-wallets

Let's say I have a friend A. I want to write a smartcontract that can access a particular NTF X in A's wallet, for example, assume my smartcontract needs the metadata of X to handle something. Of course, A needs to give me permission to do that by sending me something (like his private key). My quesion is can this work? If yes, what does A need to send to my smartcontract in order to access X?

I thought there's is a way: A would transfer X to me, and after I extract the metadata of X, I would send X back to A. But this way seems to cost too much. Is there any optimal solution?

Thanks

Comment: Smart contract cannot easily access any off-chain data. It would need to use some oracle. Metadata are usually off-chain data. If they are on-chain, your contract can read them and user don't have to give you any permission.

Comment: @ashhanai Thanks for your answer. Can you give me a link or any reference to oracle that you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: I don't know any, that would return you tokens metadata.